# Cocoapods use_frameworks! issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I found out that the way to resolve an issue, in a library i'm using, is to add  `use_frameworks!` to the podfile. When i run `pod install` on the terminal, i get the following error:

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `use_frameworks!' for #. 
>   Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

I'm using Cocoapods so i don't understand this issue. This tag is required for projects using swift, i'm using objective-c.

Comment: Well, have you tried updating cocoapod as suggested, what is your config?

Comment: @cmbarbu No... It's working now.

Comment: Maybe worth an upvoting of my comment and Keith Smiley answer ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks to me like the second part of that error message:

> Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

Is your issue. `use_frameworks!` was added in CocoaPods 0.36.0 which was just released [recently](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/).

Use `pod --version` to see what you're currently running. Assuming it's earlier than `0.36.0` you'll need to update it with

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

Which is just the same way you originally installed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to run `pod install` on my mac.
So incase anyone encounters this issue what worked for me was changing the current ruby version with [rvm](https://rvm.io/).

On console, Use `rvm list` to see what versions you have installed:
[image]

So the version of ruby that was running on my mac was ruby-2.1.2.
I changed it with:

`rvm use ruby-2.2.2`
and ran `pod install` again and it worked.